# porting a functional Component to Class based Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to convert this functional based Component to class based Component and create a PrivateAuth Component .
Here is the PrivateAuth functional Component .

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

and here is the class based Component that I tried .

```
class PrivateRoute extends React.Component{
    render(){
        console.log('this.props',this.props);
         const{ component: Component, ...rest } =this.props;
        return(
            <Route
            render={props =>
              fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
                <Component {...props} />
              ) : (
                <Redirect
                  to={{
                    pathname: "/login",
                    state: { from: props.location }
                  }}
                />
              )
            }
          />
        );
    }
}
```

I strated getting the error 
Maximum update depth exceeded.

Comment: You are not spreading rest on `Route` like in your function component: `{...rest}`. Otherwise they look the same. Are you sure the function component version worked?

Comment: What's the problem? I just tried the solution you provided and it works. Don't forget to assign `{...rest}` to the `<Route>` as well. It may be a problem in any of your components or just the way you have declared the router.

Can you check in the error if it comes from another component?

Answer (score 0):

```
  // don't spread rest here
  const{ component: Component, rest } =this.props;

    <Route
        // and you can here spread rest like before
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
          fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
```

Comment: I think OP still wants `...rest` to descructure everything except `component` into an object.